# Image.onload event not firing

Tags: javascript, image, onload-event

I'm trying to load a temporary image tag. Once that tag is done loading the image, I will set the 'src' for the img#main to the 'src' of the "temporary" image element.  The thing is, the temporary image is successfully loading (it shows up on the screen), but the onload handler doesn't seem to fire. I never get my "Image is done loading" msg.  I don't see how the temporary image can show up on the page, but not trigger its onload handler (would this happen if the browser is using a cached version of the image? But, I'm pretty sure I cleared the cache, anyway.).  By the way, I've also tried code like B) below. But that didn't seem to work either.  Also, I'm using Aptana Studio and loading my pages into my local WAMP server.  I don't know if that makes any difference. Also, the urls that I'm assigning to the 'src' are document relative (like: "images/image_1.jpg").

I would appreciate any advice anyone might have.  Thanks very much.  Mike H.

A)

```
$('img#temp').load = function(){
  mch.say('Image is done loading');
}
$('img#temp').attr('src', url);
$('img#main').attr('src', url);
```

B)

```
var tempImage = new Image();
tempImage.src = url;
tempImage.onload = function(e){
mch.say("Image is done loading");
}
```

Comment: Can you put a bigger part of your code? I don't know what `mch` is. And I'd like to see the HTML part too.

Comment: Sorry for my belated reply. I've been away from my computer. mch.say() is just a method that created to output stuff to my browser window.  As for my code snippet, I'll try to get something more coherent up soon.

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in A & B.

A) `$('img#temp').load` should be `$('#temp').on('load')` (if you're using jquery)

B) You should assign the `onload` event **before** assining the `src`.

Comment: I believe jquery uses .load() if I'm not mistaken. Your right about the source order. I just typed it wrong in the question.

Comment: @user3538389 `.load()` is used by jquery to [*load data from a server*](http://api.jquery.com/load/), but you want to catch the `onload` event, which can be done with `on('load')` (edited the answer). And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeR6t/).

Comment: Oh, right. I thought load() was a shortcut fn for .on("load", handler). Stupid mistake.

Comment: Point B here helped me resolve a similar problem I was having in which images were cached, and as a result, sometimes, an image would be already completely loaded before the onload event even got set up, thus causing processing I wanted to be performed in the onload event callback for each image to not be performed for some images. Thanks.